# Как сделать разметку сайта с помощью flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать адаптивную разметку на данном макете?

Comment: Сверстать за Вас?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
header,
content,
footer {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="menu-block">//code burgermenu</div>
  <div class="some-class">Some text</div>
  <div class="some-class">Contacts</div>
</header>

<content>
  <div class="some-class">//code burgermenu</div>
  <div class="some-class">Girl is here</div>
  <div class="some-class">Text</div>
  <div class="some-class">Date</div>
</content>

<footer>
  <div class="some-class">Social btn</div>
  <div class="some-class">Readmore</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, насчет блока контент. Внутри него есть еще 4 блока, интересует как лучше задать им размер. Будет ли правильным если я задам каждому ширину в % и запишу это в flex-basis ?

Comment: да можно но учтите мобильную версию тоже